# How to count all the lines of code in a directory recursively on Windows?

Tags: windows-7

On a Windows 7 machine, I'd like a quick way to determine the number of lines in all of the files in a directory tree, for files of a given extension.  Is there any good out of the box way to do this?

Comment: [Do you know a similar program for wc (unix word count command) on Windows?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247234/do-you-know-a-similar-program-for-wc-unix-word-count-command-on-windows

Comment: I'm familiar with wc, I wish there was a W7 equivellant.

Comment: @ (quillbreaker) There is.  The entire Linux/Unix command line toolkit is available for ALL windows based platforms. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use `Measure-Object` in powershell like this:

```bsh
PS D:\temp> dir -Recurse *.txt | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line
```

Which will return the following:

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
  168
```

Comment: While your answer is helpful and accepted by the OP, it doesn't correctly answer OP's question. The problem is in the first command in your solution - `dir -Recurse *.txt` will only process directories whose names match `*.txt`, while outputting all the files that it finds in those directories and their subtrees. But the OP wanted to process all directories while outputting only the files that match `*.txt`. To do that, you would use `dir -Recurse -Include *.txt`.

Comment: This is incorrect, the windows help on `Get-ChildItem` (which `dir` is an alias of) states that `Get-ChildItem –Path "*.txt" -Recurse` is all that is needed to get "all of the .txt files in the current directory and its subdirectories."  link: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx

Comment: @AndrewLeap I just tested it again - on Win8 with PowerShell 4.0 it works as you say. However on Win7 with PowerShell 2.0 it has the problem I described. `dir -Recurse -Include *.txt` seems to have the desired results on both of these versions.

Comment: How would someone use this to check in BOTH *.txt AND *.java (combined total)?

Comment: This doesn't work on windows 7 unless the folder your starting in has some files/folders matching the spec your searching.  EG: if you have a folder of sub folders, containing the desired files, but no files in the folder you start from and use the powershell recurse command it returns 0 and never tries to descend the folder chain.

Comment: Although to be fair, Windows 7 in 2018 feels a little disingenuous: Windows 7 (SP1, even) has been EOL since 2015. On any actively supported OS from Microsoft, this works just fine. Even on Windows 7: [update your powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx), because v2.0 is hopelessly outdated.

Comment: `(dir -Recurse *.txt | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line).Lines` will just return the property of Lines resulting in 168 in your example.

Comment: @Jeremy, forget to mention that `(dir -Recurse "*.java", (([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))+"\*.txt") | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line).Lines` to get multiple paths or extensions. Just give the dir an array.

Answer (score 11):

To expand on maweeras answer above (sorry not enough rep to comment), you can search for multiple file extensions by passing a comma-delimited array to -Include.

So for example:

```
dir -Recurse -Include *.ts,*.tsx -Exclude *node_modules* | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line
```

Comment: Only works with one extension, soon as I add another I get 0 lines

Answer (score 4):

The following works in cmd:

```
for %f in (*.TXT) do find /v /c "" "%f"
```

Or in a [.bat]:

```
for %%f in (*.TXT) do find /v /c "" "%%f"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be with [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc)

1. Download the release exe
2. Add the folder its in to the path e.g. in the CLI:
   `set path=%path%C:\Folder\Path\Cloc\Is\In`
3. Go to the top directory you want to analyze
4. Run the following commands

**For analyzing each subfolder separately**

`for /D %I in (.\*) do cd %I && cloc . && cd ..`

[image]

**For getting a joint report of all subfolders**

`cloc .`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recursively get all line for your `*.ps1;*.cs;*.js;*.txt` files

- In the current folder `.`:

```
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where/r . *.ps1;*.cs;*.js;*.txt^|find/v /c  ""')do @echo\ %i
```

- In the current drive `\`:

```
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where/r \ *.ps1;*.cs;*.js;*.txt^|find/v /c  ""')do @echo\ %i
```

- In the specified folder `C:\User\Sources`:

```
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where/r "C:\User\Sources" *.ps1;*.cs;*.js;*.txt^|find/v /c  ""')do @echo\ %i
```